# Salesforce Custom Object and field data model

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, custom-object, custom-field, data-model

I am trying to create a custom object related to a field related to the accounts objects and as well as a picklist and checkbox field. What I would like is that for every single record on the object I would like to be able to link an account, select an item from a pick list, and mark a checkbox/radio button. I would also like to be able to enter multiple items at the same time and add additional rows with the entry. My questions are how do I go about creating the data model for this and or the view? please see an example of what I am trying to achieve in the images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you been able to create the objects/relationships yet? As for the view - you won't be able to achieve that out of the box, you will need to create a custom lightning aura/web component to be able to get what you are expecting.

Comment: thanks for the tip Jayant